# Remove item from legend using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, legend

I can't remove *item* from the legend (lyr called "atikot") using arcpy with this code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

removeLyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "atikot")[0]
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"LEGEND_ELEMENT")[0]
for lyr in legend.listLegendItemLayers():
    if lyr.name == "atikot":
        legend.removeItem(lyr)
del mxd
```

The code does not work. Does anyone have an idea as to what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I tried to remove item from legend on a several mxd's and this is the resulting code:

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping
import os
import sys
from arcpy import env
import string


env.workspace = r"C:\Project"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\\" + mxdname)
    legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"LEGEND_ELEMENT")[0]
    for lyr in legend.listLegendItemLayers():
        if lyr.name == "atikot":
            legend.removeItem(lyr)
            print 'remove'
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem with your code is that you have not included an `mxd.save()` before deleting your map document (mxd) object at the end.  You're also referring to your `mxd` variable before you have assigned it.

Your modified code should look like this:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"LEGEND_ELEMENT")[0]
for lyr in legend.listLegendItemLayers():
    if lyr.name == "atikot":
        legend.removeItem(lyr)
mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Make sure that you save the map document (mxd) object **before** you delete it.